# If $f\in L^p$ prove $\int_{\Bbb R^n}p\int_0^{|f(x)|}\alpha^{p-1}\,d\alpha\,dx =p\int_0^{+\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\int_{\{|f(x)|>\alpha\}}1\,dx\,d\alpha $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$; I must prove that
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n}|f(x)|^p\,dx
=\int_{\Bbb R^n}p\int_0^{|f(x)|}\alpha^{p-1}\,d\alpha\,dx
=p\int_0^{+\infty}\alpha^{p-1}\int_{\{|f(x)|>\alpha\}}1\,dx\,d\alpha
$$
The first passage is quite clear; my problem is the second: I can interchange the integrals using Fubini-Tonelli, but I can't understand how the integration domain is changed.

I imagine it's simple, but at the moment I can't go out from this.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E=\{(x,a)\in \mathbb R^n\times [0,\infty ]\mid |f(x)|>a>0\}$ (why is it measurable ?). 
Using Fubini,

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} p dx\int_0^{|f(x)|} a^{p-1}da=p\int dx\int a^{p-1}\chi_E^x da=p\int  a^{p-1}da\int \chi_E^a dx=p\int  a^{p-1}da\int_{|f(x)|>a}dx.$$

Notice that the notation $\chi_E^a$ mean that $a$ is fixed (it's not a power), i.e. $\chi_E^a: x\longmapsto \chi_E(x,a)$ and $\chi_E^x: a\longmapsto \chi_E(x,a)$ and $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function, i.e. $\chi_E(y)=\begin{cases}1&y\in E\\ 0&y\notin E\end{cases}$.